# Angular 4 Injecting route in the APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular

I am trying to retrieve a data present in the url in my APP_INITIALIZER

app.module.ts

```
export function init(config: ConfigService, router: Router) {
    return () => config.load(router);
}


providers : [
    ...
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: init,
      deps: [ConfigService, Router],
      multi: true
    },
    ConfigService 
    ... 
]
```

config-service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService 
    load(router: Router): Promise<any> {
        console.log('current url : ' + router.url);
        return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => resolve()));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting

```
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppBrowserModule in ./AppBrowserModule@-1:-1
```

I also tried using the `Injector` in the constructor but it didn't work either.

Is what I am trying to do even feasible ?

Comment: can you create a reproducible problem on stackblitz?

Comment: Cheers mate, that should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I was trying to do isn't feasible since the APP_INITIALIZER happens before the router init.
https://medium.com/hackernoon/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e

Comment: Depending on your needs you could use APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER: https://angular.io/api/core/APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER

Comment: The link is dead. This seems to be the same article: https://medium.com/hackernoon/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e

Answer (score 12):

config-service.ts can be rewritten as below.

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService
    constructor(private injector: Injector){}

    load(): Promise<any> {
        const router = this.injector.get(Router);
        console.log('current url : ' + router.url);
        return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => resolve()));
    }
}
```

No need to inject Router as a dependency in app.module.ts.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer pointed out, the APP_INITIALIZER is triggered before the router initializes. In this scenario, you can simply use `window.location.pathname`, or any other properties under `window.location`.