# Angular 8: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency - ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, cyclic-dependency

I am trying to integrate the `APP_INITIALIZER` from Angular in my project in order to do some functionalities before start the application. The problem comes when I use the **ActivatedRoute** from Angular in my service.

The error is:

```
Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
```

I suppose that I am using some import twice internally or something like this. Basically i tried with some other configurations but at the end always is throwing me the same error.

**STACKBLITZ EXAMPLE:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhpe7m

Expected behavior: Just to be able to retrieve some QueryParams by the ActivatedRoute service and do some functionality with them before run the Angular app

Comment: Thanks for the formating @nircraft :)

Comment: In shared stackblitz :  the `AppLoadModule` works as another feature module, Your `APP_INITIALIZER` should be in the `AppModule` which is referenced and bootstrapped in `main.ts`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APP\_INITIALIZER raises "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef\_" when used with a custom Http provider that is redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767019/app-initializer-raises-cannot-instantiate-cyclic-dependency-applicationref-w)

Comment: I know, but I was trying to do it separately, like this example: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/

Comment: you can also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441139/cannot-instantiate-cyclic-dependency-applicationref-error-in-ngmodule

Comment: you are not having any `routes`

Comment: Yes, because for now I don't need any other page on my application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got your problem just remove router from your 'appLoaderService'

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {} // remove this dependency
```

You are getting cyclic dependency since you are injecting route in the config which initializes your app.

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832508/angular-4-injecting-route-in-the-app-initializer)

Simply, remove this since you are not using it anyways.

However if you indent to use route before your bootstrapping component loads, you can go for resolver or guards.

As mentioned, it is not possible to use routes inside APP_INITIALIZER, *though there is a way**, but i would better suggest to use Resolver as following:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<any> {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (route) {
        console.log(route.params);
        console.log(route.queryParams);
      }
 }
return promise;
}
```

[Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) for reference

**EDIT**
Here is what you will have after placing code in resolver :

[image]

Comment: I know that, but in fact i need to use it, i was not showing it before in the stackblitx example but now it is updated. Because I need to store the query params retrieved at the start of the application in some variables.

Comment: i had faced the similar issue, if you put route inside your config, even then your component will not be loaded, now suppose you initializes couple of things in your app, you cannot show spinner component since "config" is the first thing which is loaded, moreover it is absurd to show your client blank screen unless you are done with all dependencies inside app.config. Let, me edit my answer, how can you read your query params via Resolver

Comment: It make sense, but how can i call the resolve method passing to it the route object? Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhpe7m

Comment: here check this [example for you](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhpe7m), please note as best practices you have to keep separate file for Resolver, and believe me this will help you resolving so many concerns in near future, which i had faced.

Comment: wow it seems like it is working for yoy, can you share this code in a stackblitz? the current one seems like its not updated.Thanks a lot for your helping @yanky_cranky

Comment: I don't really get the solution, and the stackblitz example it's not working as the image in your comment on top. What is exactly doing the appload service now? Thanks a lot

Comment: My bad, shared you the wrong url, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mb1tsx) you go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197036/discussion-between-jgascona-and-yanky-cranky).

Answer (score 14):

Make sure to include HttpClientModule in your app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      HttpClientModule
   ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to a loop in dependency injection, for example you have injected a service into itself in its constructor!

Comment: This was my answer!  I had code that was Injecting itself instead of the MatDialogRef
@Inject(ThresholdRequirementEditComponent) public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<ThresholdRequirementEditComponent>

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `ConfigService` loading its configuration using `http` service.

This `ConfigService` was injected inside an `HttpInterceptor`.

But `http` service needs `HttpInterceptor` and `HttpInterceptor` needs `ConfigService` that needs `http`.

**A simple workaround solution** was to use `from(fetch('/config').then(resp=>resp.json()))` instead of `http.get('/config')` inside the `HttpInterceptor` to avoid the cyclic dependency.

In any case there is no need to have an  `HttpInterceptor` running for loading `HttpInterceptor`'s configuration.

Answer (score -5):

I solved it by updating the package using the following code.

```
ng add @angular/localize
```