# nullinjectorerror no provider for store if importing the store module from a child module

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

In my `app.module.ts` file I set up a store with:

```
imports: [
  StoreModule.forRoot(
    { soundtrackState: soundtrackReducer }
  ),
  EffectsModule.forRoot(
    [
      // SoundtrackEffects TODO add some effects
    ]
  ),
  StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 15, logOnly: environment.production }),    
  CoreModule,
```

Now, if I move this code out and into the `core.module.ts` file then I get the `nullinjectorerror no provider for store` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any other module that root you need to use `forFeature` and I guess app.module' store should be initialized with code you wrote.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forFeature(groupModuleEffects),
    StoreModule.forFeature(GROUPS_FEATURE_NAME, groupModuleReducers),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production }),
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class GroupsModule {}
```

Comment: I already tried the `forFeature` as in `StoreModule.forFeature('soundtrackFeature', {
      soundtrackState: soundtrackReducer
    }),` in another module. But it gives a `Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! SoundtrackStore` error.

Comment: @Stephane Seems this cyclic error is not releated to ngrx. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206026/angular-8-cannot-instantiate-cyclic-dependency-activatedroute. forFeature should be the way to go as it's said in documentation

Answer (score 0):

Some of your services may imported the store via

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store/src/store'
```

or

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store/store'
```

Make sure the imports are imported from,

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'
```

If everything fine, there may be the problem with store definition. Please share your code of `app.module.ts` and `core.module.ts` with stackblitz or other way. So we can resolve the problem.